# How can I hook up a PHP server?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, php, webserver

I have a php page I want to test on a server. Is there a server that runs through Terminal.app that supports PHP? I read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php) tutorial, but either I did it wrong or it didn't work. How can I start up a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to set this up is to use MAMP. You can download it for free from here: https://www.mamp.info

It sets up a local and isolated PHP/MySQL/Apache server that you can start and stop at any time.

It's a web developers friend if you want to keep your Mac system somewhat isolated from the development work.